# Error after creating the drop down SSRS report parameter

Tags: concatenation, ssrs-2012

[Table structure image atached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i1Uz.png)

I have DataSet already created which has all the fields from the below query.

I am trying to concatenate First and Last Name in a report drop down parameter. I tried creating a calculated field in the DataSet, but dint work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
a.DiseId, 
n1.LastName, 
n1.FirstName, 
n1.MiddleName,
 ...............................
FROM Table1
```

I also tried creating a separate DataSet by creating the below query -

```
Select FirstName, lastName, convert(varchar(50),FirstName) + ' ' +
convert(varchar(50),lastName) as FullName from Table2
```

**I can see the Concatenation result in a drop down but I get this below error, this error occured only after I created the new data set with concatenation query.**

An error occurred during local report processing.
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

How do I go about to remove the error and create the filter??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
select Distinct FirstName||' '||LastName FullName from table2
```

Then in your first dataset, use

```
...where FirstName||' '||LastName = :ParameterName
```

or if you have multiple selections, do this

```
...where FirstName||' '||LastName in (:ParameterName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. || dint work instead + ' ' + worked. This is what I have in my query now. select Distinct FirstName + ' ' + lastName AS FullName 
from table2. Now i don't see the error, it would have caused because of convert(varchar(50)).